# Extracting the Values from the below Statement

Tags: c#

```
var tmp = myCollection.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                      .Select(y => new { 
                                Id = y.Key, 
                                Quantity = y.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
                       });
```

I would like it implement the above statement. However, how do I extract the ID and Quanity Values so I can use elsewhere?

Comment: `tmp` is going to be an array (IEnumerable in fact) of an anonymous object containing both properties, Id and Quantity.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico - not an array, just an instance of an `IEnumerable`.  All arrays implement `IEnumerable`, but not all `IEnumerable`s are arrays :)

Comment: @matt, I know. And I mentioned after I used the word `array`.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico, my point was that this invocation does *not* return an array.  It returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, which is distinctly different from a concrete instance of an array.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

After this statement, the variable `tmp` (which is a bad name, but that's another story), will  be an `IEnumerable` of objects containing the `Id` and `Quantity` values.

You could use it like this, among other possible ways:

```
foreach (var item in tmp) {
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", item.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Quantity: {0}", item.Quantity);
}
```